# Was I wrong to make this edit adding blockquotes to external content?

Tags: discussion, edits, specific-question, attribution

I recently edited [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30967131/why-doesnt-stdstring-contain-a-split-method#30967198) in order to place the bulk of the answer in a block quote, since it was in fact a quote from a Quora post and I didn't feel that was as clear as it could be. (Particularly for users with screen readers, I feel the semantics of block quoting are more appropriate.) However, [someone else (revision 4)](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/30967198/revisions) recently suggested and had approved an edit to remove the block quoting, with the reason "Its difficult to read it".

I disagree with the assertion that the quoting somehow makes it harder to read, and I suspect robo-reviewing explains how this edit got approved, but I have no interest in starting an edit war here. So, sanity check me: was my original edit correct, or is it sufficient to state that the remainder of the post is a quote, and leave the formatting off for the sake of readability?

Comment: I find it strange that an upvoted, accepted answer is a verbatim copy of a post from a different forum. How did this answer ever get such positive feedback? Your edit is correct because it highlights the structure of the answer.

Comment: @Tichodroma: The post originally mentions that it's copying from content of a link, so the attribution is more or less OK. As for the voting, I think there is nothing wrong with people upvoting good content. I don't know what else can be done if the content from other source adequately answer the question. (As for the formatting, I agree that copied content should be quoted.)

Comment: I would reject revision 4.But at revision 3 I don't like adding block-quote on content.Revision 2 was better readable than revision 3

Comment: It would be nice if highly voted content on SO could be a bit more than a mere Google hit aggregation.  Which I assume is what this is really about.  Any "it's hard to read" motivation to edit the content is pretty nonsensical, just go read the original.

Comment: What is strange is that the author of the answer is a very high-rep user, but didn't bother using quote devices. Without the quotes, the answer appears to have been written by them, which is not good.

Comment: Just as an FYI to anyone who needs to quote paragraphs.  As long as the start of the paragraph starts with `>` at the beginning of the line, the whole paragraph will be quoted.  So, rather than inserting the `>` at the beginning of each line in the paragraph, it is sufficient (simpler, quicker) to insert the `>` once.  Even code works like that (though use greater-than blank for code -- and it is arguably better as greater-than blank in all cases).

Comment: I'm still finding it hard to accept that any self-respecting member of society can somehow be *unaware* of the concept of giving credit where it's due. But there is simply *no* excuse for *removing* attribution or any clear indication of sourced content once it has been put there. None whatsoever.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler For what it's worth, all of those extra `>`'s get added automatically when you highlight text and click the "blockquote" button.  So I doubt someone typed them all manually (although I'm not sure why that feature really behaves that way).

Comment: @jadarnel27: which mainly goes to show you how often I've used that button (precisely 0 times is correct!).  Thanks for reassuring me that it wasn't a manual labour of necessity.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Yeah, if it actually required all that effort, I wouldn't have done it and this question never would have existed. :)

Comment: It is hard to read. It looks ugly. It is what it is. Not sure why this question has so much attention.

Comment: @DisplayNameismissing I actually disagree that it's hard to read (seems the same to me), but even if it was, I think that's largely secondary to making sure we're citing our sources correctly. If quotes are hard to read, we should bring that up as a CSS change to the SO team, not stop using quotes.

Answer (score 68, accepted):

Your edit was correct. If material is quoted from an external source, then it needs to be *clearly* marked as such. The original answer did mention it already, but it was way too easy to miss. Clearly marking quoted material is important because while such quoted material may (or may not) be fair use in the context of the answer, it is *not* contributed to SO by the author / copyright holder, it is *not* CC-licensed, and that can have significant consequences if you want to do anything with the answer other than read it. A simple example of when this matters would be if you would want to use the quoted text in a presentation.

Comment: `The original answer did mention it already, but it was way too easy to miss.` Thanks for understanding and apologies to all for missing to add the quotes :( +1

Comment: @Rahul Tripathi: You really need to start cultivating a habit of formatting your quoted material correctly *as soon as you copy and paste content from elsewhere*. You have been contributing for several years - you have had *ample* time to learn to do this. It is *not* difficult to do.

Comment: It must be CC BY-SA licensed, or it cannot be submitted to StackOverflow at all.  By pasting it in the "Answer Question" textfield and hitting submit, the user certifies that they have the right to the material they post and agrees to contribute it under CC BY-SA.  There are no exceptions made related to use of quotations.  If you don't have the right to do that, don't post it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Not even you follow it that way. Going through your recent posting history, you yourself quoted non-CC-licensed material in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30719748) and [this other answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30628371). You probably have dozens of similar quotations in your own answers, as do I, and as do most people here. If there is something wrong with that, I encourage you to show how you believe such material should be presented (if it should be at all).

Comment: @hvd: I believe that usage of this very short quote in my larger work constitutes fair use, I am copyright holder for the larger work, and I choose to license it under CC BY-SA.  What's the problem?

Comment: @BenVoigt In that case, I think you missed the "while such quoted material may (or may not) be fair use" bit in my answer. You seemed to contradict my answer, but your last comment seems as if we're actually in full agreement, we're just focusing on two different but related areas.

Comment: @Rahul, you would do well to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/help/referencing) - the guidelines are based on those hashed out on meta over the course of several years, and abiding by them is at minimum a show of good faith.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: Also your saying "it cannot be submitted at all" implies that even fair use is excluded as long as the content you're quoting isn't licensed accordingly.

Comment: @BenVoigt the third-party material you quote in the answers linked make up (in at least one case) more than 50% of the total content you posted. I'm not sure that commenting on a majority share of copyrighted material automatically means fair-use and thus rights to re-license the material. Before slamming down the standards hammer, make sure your own fingers aren't in the way.

Comment: @TechnikEmpire: Since I'm pretty sure whitespace is not protected by copyright, your assertion of "more than 50%" fails.  And in any case, the excerpt is less than 10% of the source cited.  On top of that, the manual page is licensed under conditions which appear to be compatible with CC BY-SA, so I'm not actually relying on fair use in that case.

Comment: @hvd: I didn't miss that.  You're the one who said that the content is NOT CC licensed.  I said that *if* that is actually true, then it can't be posted here.

Comment: @BenVoigt Even if the answer as a whole is CC-licensed, and if the quoted material is allowable fair use, then the quoted material is *still* not CC-licensed. That's the whole point of my answer: that distinction still matters. For a more extreme example that is hopefully more convincing to you: if every individual sentence of a book happens to be quoted in *some* answer on SO, then I still can't assemble those sentences into a new book, claim that I found them on SO that legally distributes them under a CC license, and redistribute a word-for-word identical copy of that book.

Comment: @hvd: No amount of assembling answers or answer fragments is going to get you to word-for-word identical copy of the original, because the new work is going to be punctuated by all the attributions.  Besides which, a court is going to find that you did not, in fact, create a derivative work of the answers, but of the book, based on the fact that no original elements of the answers appear in your work.  Assembling the entire book including the attribution of and additional content from the answers presumably is legal, because SE does exactly that in its data dumps.

Comment: @BenVoigt So if you agree that the quoted material doesn't become CC-licensed merely by including it in a CC-licensed answer, does that affect your claim that if material isn't CC-licensed, it must not be submitted to SO at all? If not, why not?

Comment: @hvd I'm saying that to the best of my understanding, possessing CC BY-SA licenses to a bunch of answers with small quotes from a common work does not confer any right to reuse the organizational structure of the original source.  Making a derivative of a bunch of answers looks like a content database dump, not the book they quoted from.

Comment: @BenVoigt If the organizational structure of the original source is protected by copyright at all (it depends), then still, if I manage to create an identical structure without having the original book available, that is an absolute defence to claims of copyright infringement: I can easily prove I did not copy the structure from a source where such copying is prohibited. As for your earlier claim that it would be seen as a derivative work of the original book, not the SO answers, again, that's the point I'm making in my answer, so I really struggle to see what issue you have with it.

Comment: @hvd: Are we talking about a work that contains substantially the same content as the common source, or is (your words) "word-for-word identical"?  You say that you can easily prove that you didn't copy the structure, but statistically your chances of exactly duplicating it without copying are miniscule.  Perhaps the details of this supposed "proof" of yours would sway me, but initial indications are that if I were on that jury, I would find by a preponderance of the evidence that whether or not you referred to answers, you also referred to the book and copied from it.

Comment: @BenVoigt Simply make sure you have no access to the book when you're doing the work if you know there's a risk you'll get accused of copying from the book, that's the easy way to prove you didn't. But that won't convince you here that it's possible. :) Perhaps think of the C++ standard, which isn't CC-licensed and is very frequently quoted. Sections and paragraphs are numbered, and those numbers are typically included here. Even for larger individual paragraphs that aren't quoted in their entirety, there is much overlap in quotes, allowing the pieces to be put together like a jigsaw puzzle.