# Posts edited by other than the author seem never to get read by anyone else?

Tags: discussion, edits

I have had the experience a couple of times that a question I've posed has been edited by someone else, once making a lot of changes that barely retained the approach I took to ask, and the other corrected simple formatting errors (one word in a sentence marked as code and making the yellow quotation of a copied paragraph - proper but unnecessary changes as far as readability).

In both cases, the editor was the first responder, and neither post was read again by anyone else.

Is it possible that having been edited is some stigma against a question to the community, and that should be considered when edits are made by readers who read only to edit but not to respond to the question?

Comment: (1) It is the other way around: [good edits tend to help you getting a good answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/343680/2751851). (2) As Suraj Rao points out, the formatting improvements in the second edit you describe are fine. As for the first edit it is hard to give my two cents on whether it went too far without seeing it.

Comment: I don't have a problem with editing in general, I understand it as necessary to improve the value of the community reservoir of information.

Comment: I see 14 down votes to what I think would be a reasonable question. That seems rather mean spirited. Otherwise responses hereto were fully comprehensible and appreciated.

Comment: Meta gives out downvotes like candy. That is sometimes justified by claiming Meta downvotes can express disagreement, though such a rationale would be a stretch in the case of this question. It it serves as solace, Meta downvotes do not have any tangible effect on your account.

Answer (score 8):

> Is it possible that having been edited is some stigma against a question to the community?

No. Editing is only done to improve a post. In fact, this will bump the post higher in the active list and will get more attention to your question.

Stack Overflow being a repository of Q&A needs to maintain quality standards and so improvements in posts are necessary. I also disagree regarding the block quoting of copied paragraph being unnecessary. It is [essential](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297585/4826457) to provide the citation.

> ... edits are made by readers who read only to edit but not to respond to the question?

You also imply readers who edit need to respond to your question. This is not required of them. They may not necessarily have the domain knowledge or they may not know the solution to whatever you asked.

Comment: The one edit I found less than valuable was one in which the editor didn't seem to understand the intent of the question, and so made it less understandable. However, I accept the fact that the root of misunderstanding must have been my own original explanation.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, as someone who both edits and responds (whether in comments or with an answer): No. There is no stigma - nothing that would tell anyone "don't respond to this".

I sometimes wonder why the person who did the editing didn't change one thing, or another, that are obvious to me when a question is something in my expertise.

But if I'm answering or commenting, I don't even pay attention to it's have been edited (or not). I'm concentrating fully on the content.

Where I will look at the editing is in some of the review queues, mostly whether the edit is from the original poster or not.

Comment: Thank you. I hope you would have knowledge over my realm of ignorance.